# More than one controller in one Bundle (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, controller

Is it possible to do more than one controller in Symfony? And if yes, how can I do it? (Controller, routing etc)

Because now I have:

Directory "Controller" and inside "DefaultController.php" (It has 1000 lines of code like now.)

Directory Resources->Config->Routing.yml (Here I have all routings).

Directory Resources->views->Default (In this dir I have all views).

Is it possible to make more controllers? For example one controller will have only indexAction(), other will have addclientAction() etc.

Comment: Just an idea: how would it be one `ClientController` with `add`, `update`, etc. actions?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just change your routing.yml and call to action:  `contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you will have controlelrs at src/MyApp/SomeBundle/Controller/

```
class OneController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     ....
    }
}

class TwoController extends Controller
{
    public function addclientAction()
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

you routing.yml should looks like

```
my_route_index:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: MyAppSomeBundle:One:index }

my_route_addclient:
    pattern:   /addclient/
    defaults:  { _controller: MyAppSomeBundle:Two:addclient }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible.
You can see an example [here](https://github.com/djuro/sfmdbBlog/blob/master/Controller/PostController.php):